# "The Image passed to the ImageVisualManager cannot be frozen" WPF exception

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I'm trying to render a visual to a WPF RenderTargetBitmap I cache in window creation.

```
 RenderTargetBitmap rtb;
```

In my window constructor,

```
 public FooWindow()
 {
     rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(500, 500, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
 }
```

Later in user-invoked code (requesting a screenshot) -

```
 // ... 
 Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
 rtb.Render(window);
 rtb.Freeze();

 // rtb used further
 BitmapFrame bmpFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap);
 // ...
```

However I get the following exception on rtb.Render(..)

```
[System.ArgumentException]: {"The Image passed to the ImageVisualManager cannot be frozen."}
```

It appears to work the first time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is freezing the RenderTargetBitmap and then trying to re-use it. To fix you can do one of two things

1. Create a new render target bitmap for every request
2. Do not freeze the render target bitmap (Remove the 'rtb.Freeze() line' and keep using same instance). Given the usage of caching a single instance and trying to reuse it, you do not want to freeze it at all.

Solution #1 is not recommended in performance sensitive code because creating the RenderTargetBitmap can be expensive. There is no real need to freeze it if you expect to re-use it.